# How to Change the color of child divider of ExpanableListView by layout xml file?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to change the color of child divider of `ExpandableListView` by writing:

```
 android:childDivider="@drawable/yellow"
```

in layout file. However, when I collapse the item, I found the background of the `ExpandableListView` turn yellow (`@drawable/yellow`) , but I just want to change the color of child divider. Who can tell me why? To my surprise, if I change it by java code like

```
expandableListView.setChildDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow));
```

it works normally. It is very weird, who can tell me the reason?

```
<!-- if I set childDivider in Layout xml, it can't work normally. 
     However, if set childDivider in java code, it work normally -->

<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/yellow"
    android:childDivider="@drawable/yellow"
    />
```

Comment: A screenshot of what you see would help greatly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> > create a drawable with small height and set it to childDivider
> >     property
>
> "child_separator.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/child_separator_color"/>
    <size android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

> expandable list view:

```
android:childDivider="@drawable/child_separator"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply set child divider as the color of your choice.

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list_shopping"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:childDivider="@color/LightGrey"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Comment: Not working for me. I don´t see any divider

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove `android:divider="@drawable/yellow"` from your layout. This should resolve your problem if I understood it correctly.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! however,maybe you missunderstand me. I means that if I write "android:childDivider="@drawable/yellow" the background of ExpandListView will become all yellow(in your image is still black as usual).

Comment: I just used your code and tried to guess what was wrong. Please add screenshot of what you see to the question.

Comment: Then upload it to some place and give me the link.